# Schedule Thread only once.

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

How to fix my thread to schedule initial delay of thread for 2 min and don't schedule it again. (i.e., schedule only for once)

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void myJob() {
     Thread.sleep(12000);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring scheduling task - run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) in this case. It is an ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.

> ScheduledFuture schedule(Callable callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
>
> Creates and executes a ScheduledFuture that becomes enabled after the
>   given delay.
>
> callable - the function to execute
>   delay - the time from now to delay execution
>   unit - the time unit of the delay

```
  ScheduledExecutorService service = null;

    service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    service.schedule(() -> {
        myMethodNameWhichIWantToExecute();
    }, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    if (service != null) service.shutdown();
```