# Set custom system date to Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz

I need to execute scheduled tasks with customizable system dates, for example, I should be able to set the scheduler date to 2019-01-15, in this scenario, the scheduler must execute all tasks scheduled on that date, understanding that the current date is 2019-02-12. At the moment, I've seen solutions only for time zone, using Spring or Quartz.
Thanks!.

Comment: How do you expect to execute the tasks on 2019-01-15 if the date is in the past ?

Comment: @AK47 that's the problem, I need to set the scheduler system date to X, and at the same time I've could have scheduled tasks to be executed at `code`"0 0 17 ? * MON,WED,FRI"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) module:

```
private TaskScheduler scheduler;

Runnable exampleRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing task");
    }
};

@Async
public void executeTaskT() {
    ScheduledExecutorService localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(localExecutor);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date scheduledDate = dateFormat.parse("12-02-2019", dateFormat);

    scheduler.schedule(exampleRunnable, scheduledDate);
}

executeTaskT(); //call it somewhere after the spring application has been configured
```

For more information, see:
[Spring scheduling task - run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once)