# How to run method in java spring only one time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to know is it possible to run a method only one time in java spring boot with `schedule` or `spring job`?
I did that with temp variable as switch but I am looking for better and cleaner way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once

Comment: One time per application start? One specific point in time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring scheduling task - run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once)

Comment: you could also create a bean class and put the code in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method - https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: Explain the use case also, so we can give you better hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a component class that implements `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner`, So it will be automatically invoked after the app will start

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
       myService.save();

    }
}
```