# How to run @Scheduled job at exact time for once in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

Let's say I want to run a job for once in 06.02.2020 13:50. How can I do that?

By using expression below I can achive that it will run at 13:50 today. But it will be run next year too. But I want this to run just once.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 50 13 6 2 ?")
```

Comment: `why do you need a cron job if it has to be run only once

Comment: @salsinga How can achive that this job will be run at 06.02.2020 13:50 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround to your solution. Just use the scheduled annotation as it is but Use Date with it. That is

```
    String targetDate="2020-02-06 13:50:00";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(targetDate);
    if(new Date().getTime()==date.getTime())
    {
      then put your logic here.
   }
```

edit -> Just checking the year would be enough right. So you can do this.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 50 13 6 2 ?")
public void doTheJobForOnceInSpecificTime() {
    if (Year.now().getValue() == 2020) {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think it is nearly impossible to get exactly same time in if statement. So comparing just the year can be enough. If you agree with me you can consider to edit the answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: Yes, Comparing the years should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

if you add the year, at last, it will execute only once.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 50 13 6 2 ? 2020")
```

Comment: No. It will raise IllegalStateException at startup. "Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 52 13 6 2 ? 2020")"