# How to trigger a service method to run only once in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am having a process that runs for a certain period (fromDate to toDate) and after this process will end need to do some post process activities which needs to be trigger two days after the process is ended. What is the best way to achieve this.?
Two approaches i am able to find is either using Quatz scheduler or [TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once)

Bonus Scenario :-
If the service method fails due to some issue on the t+2 day then retrigger the same method on the next day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347233/spring-scheduling-task-run-only-once