# Stop Spring scheduler after some instances are run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz, spring-scheduled

I have a requirement where I want to execute a particular spring boot application n number of times based upon the number (n) provided in the parameter. I am using spring boot and thought of using spring scheduler to do this. Can spring scheduler be used to schedule a task for 4-5 times and then stop ?

I need to have a separate log file, output files generated for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with the help of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30347649/13184919

You should make a counter by initializing an `int counter = 0;` and increase it every time it runs, then checks if it is more than your desired number and you call `scheduledFuture.cancel(true);`